# Deploying App to Azure Kubernetes Service fails. My Global Admin account lacks permissions / scope

Tags: azure, kubernetes

That's a long question, sorry.

I'm doing a course in Git and we're on the step to push an app to AKS.  Have asked for support via PluralSight, have yet to hear back.  Sort of on my own here.

The result should be successful deploy to AKS.  It makes no sense that my account would raise this flag.

Tried review of my account permissions, I do in fact have Global Admin privileges.  The account should work for the action of listing credentials over the scope rather vaguely described in the error.

The full error is, with my account GUID and subscription GUID redacted:

Error: ***"error":***"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client '****' with object id '****' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/accessProfiles/listCredential/action' over scope '/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/***/accessProfiles/clusterAdmin' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."***

I was surprised to use the object Id (guid) and search for it in Azure portal to find it's my account and has Global Admin role assigned.  Global Admin role should be able to do it all.

The env and secrets variables are all used in the first job and these work.  The first job build-deploy-image runs flawlessly.

The YAML for the 2nd job in the workflow is:

deploy-to-aks:

```
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'

  needs: build-deploy-image
      
  #env:
    #NAMESPACE: dummy
  
  steps:
  
  - uses: actions/checkout@main
  
  # Set the target Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster. 
  - uses: azure/aks-set-context@v1
    with:
      creds: '${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS_DEMO }}'
      cluster-name: ${{ secrets.AKS_NAME_DEMO }}
      resource-group: ${{ secrets.AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP }}

  # Create namespace if doesn't exist
  # - run: |
  #    kubectl create namespace ${{ env.NAMESPACE }} --dry-run -o json | kubectl apply -f -

  # Create image pull secret for ACR
  - uses: azure/k8s-create-secret@v1
    with:
      container-registry-url: ${{ env.ACR_LOGON_SERVER }}
      container-registry-username: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID_DEMO }}
      container-registry-password: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD_DEMO }}
      secret-name: ${{ secrets.AKS_SECRET }}
      # namespace: ${{ env.NAMESPACE }}

  # Deploy app to AKS
  - uses: azure/k8s-deploy@v1
    with:
      manifests: |
        manifests/deployment.yml
        manifests/service.yml
      images: |
        ${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
      imagepullsecrets: |
        ${{ secrets.AKS_SECRET }}
      #namespace: ${{ env.NAMESPACE }}
```

Comment: Note that, Global Administrator works only for tenant related operations like managing users, applications etc... in Azure AD. In your case, you need to have proper RBAC role under your subscription. Try assigning **Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role** to your user account under AKS cluster Access control(IAM).

Comment: You can also **elevate access** for Global Administrator to manage subscriptions by following this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin#elevate-access-for-a-global-administrator).

Comment: Added this role to my Global Admin and my owner account.  These were the only 2 members to select.

Note there is a service principal account.  

Its interesting that the id is actually for the SP account.  The id, when using it to search does bring up my owner account.

Added this role to the service principal.

Adding to all 3 accounts, global admin, owner, SP, does not work.

Comment: Verified I already to have elevated access, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

There are two Azure roles you can apply to an Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) user or group:

**Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role**

Allows access to
Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterAdminCredential/action API call. This API call lists the cluster admin credentials. Downloads kubeconfig for the clusterAdmin role.

**Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role**

Allows access to Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterUserCredential/action API call. This API call lists the cluster user credentials. Downloads kubeconfig for clusterUser role.

> Note:
>
> 1. On clusters that use Azure AD, users with the clusterUser role have an empty kubeconfig file that prompts a login. Once logged in, users have access based on their Azure AD user or group settings. Users with the clusterAdmin role have admin access.
> 2. On clusters that don’t use Azure AD, the clusterUser role has same effect of clusterAdmin role.

When you are using Azure AD based RBAC for your Azure Kubernetes, You need to enable the Azure AD integrated rbac for your kubernetes by referring this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-azure-rbac).

You can create a cluster with Azure AD RBAC with the command below or from Portal:-

```bash
az aks create -g myResourceGroup -n myManagedCluster --enable-aad --enable-azure-rbac
```

And then assign Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin role to the Azure AD user or your service principal like below:-

```bash
az role assignment create --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Admin" --assignee <AAD-ENTITY-ID> --scope $AKS_ID
```

You can run Azure CLI commands in your github action workflow to create and manage your kubernetes cluster instead of using

```yaml
azure/k8s-deploy@v1
```

task like below:-

**Github action workflow script:-**

```yaml
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      # Checkout code
      - uses: actions/checkout@main

      # Log into Azure
      - uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: "Run az commands"
        run: |
              az group create --name myResourceGroup --location westus2
              az aks create -g myResourceGroup -n myManagedCluster --enable-aad --enable-azure-rbac
              AKS_ID=$(az aks show -g myResourceGroup -n myManagedCluster --query id -o tsv)
              az role assignment create --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Admin" --assignee <AAD-ENTITY-ID> --scope $AKS_ID
```

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer.

I'm onto another section of the course but will fully apply this input ASAP.

Curious, got no email about the answer but I see it came in yesterday.

Will get back to you on it.