# Token refresh error due to incorrect client secret for Service Principal

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have been through the setup, following along with a course, 3 times.  I'm retracing my steps to get this working myself.

The client secret (password), in the variable $SP_PASSWORD is correct.

Related link is here: [Deploying App to Azure Kubernetes Service fails. My Global Admin account lacks permissions / scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762318/deploying-app-to-azure-kubernetes-service-fails-my-global-admin-account-lacks-p). This link at first was the only thing that was failing.  It shows the code for the 2nd job in the YAML workflow.

The first job in the workflow runs.  Setting up the AcrPull for the Kubernetes service to do its thing works.

Creating the AKS, with this code, I get the error following the line for the az aks create. **Important Edit: The AKS DOES get created in Azure.**  It is only this permissions error that is concerning:

michael [ ~ ]$ az aks create --resource-group $RG_NAME --name $AKS_NAME --node-count 2 --generate-ssh-keys --attach-acr $ACR_NAME --service-principal $SP_ID --subscription $RG_SUBSCRIPTION --client-secret $SP_PASSWORD

(CreateRoleAssignmentError) Token refresh failed with invalid client secret error. Make sure the client secret specified is correct. This may also happen due to propagation delay for recently created service principals.

Code: CreateRoleAssignmentError
Message: Token refresh failed with invalid client secret error. Make sure the client secret specified is correct. This may also happen due to propagation delay for recently created service principals.

And, I get a bogus container created in Azure.

In the screen shot below, the correct container (resource group), container_yourname_rg_TechConf2023, gets created.

The bogus container / resource group is highlighted here:

[image: Screen shot showing correct and bogus resource group containers]

There were other resource groups present that were doing nothing.

The Default resource group, deleted it. And a Network Watcher RG, likewise deleted it.

The bogus resource group that got created on the 2 earlier tries was also removed.

Retraced all my steps, all the secrets used, etc. I don't see what I missed.

This certainly points right to the password being wrong.  But ... after 3 tries, carefully retracing steps, it's the right password.

So before, what was happening was the permissions issue covered in the first post, some 2-3 weeks back.

Now what happens is the bogus Resource Group and the claim that the client secret is incorrect.  So, now we're not even getting to the point where the permissions error showed up. (related post, above)

Since this mysterious bogus Resource Group just started rearing its head, my thought is whatever is causing it to be created is where the real issue is.  The client secret is a red herring :)

Finding and resolving this question will likely also solve the permissions issue posted earlier.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what caused the issue but again, updating all Git Secrets, etc. the whole way through resolved the issue.

Evidently when copying secret values, a typo happened.

This is working now.  Just ran
az aks create --resource-group $RG_NAME --name $AKS_NAME --node-count 2 --generate-ssh-keys --attach-acr $ACR_NAME --service-principal $SP_ID --subscription $RG_SUBSCRIPTION --client-secret $SP_PASSWORD

after the container / registry, etc. were all done with the first job in the workflow.

So, all is good.  Thanks to all who took the time to look.